# How can i add an image to the end stroke of UIBezierPath, showing in the screenshot link

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, uibezierpath

Here is the link of the image, the sun will move as per the progress of teh progress view.
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMP04.png

SunProgressView class:

```
   import UIKit

   class SunProgressView: UIView {
    
    enum GradientType {
        case blueAndRedOrange /// we are using this gradient...
        case orange
        case redAndBlue
    }
    
    var gradientType: GradientType = .blueAndRedOrange {
        didSet {
            //To prevent to add multiple layers
            guard self.layer.sublayers != nil else {return}
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.layer.sublayers = nil
                self.addProgressBar(radius: self.radius, progress: self.progress)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var lineWidth: CGFloat = 7 {
        didSet {
            guard self.layer.sublayers != nil else {return}
            self.layer.sublayers = nil
            self.addProgressBar(radius: radius, progress: progress)
        }
    }
    
    var progress: CGFloat = 40 {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if self.layer.sublayers != nil {
                    self.addAnimation()
                } else {
                    self.addProgressBar(radius: self.radius, 
     progress: self.progress)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    //  MARK: - Private properties
    
    private var location: [NSNumber]? {
        switch gradientType {
        case .blueAndRedOrange: return [0.35, 0.38, 0.40, 0.60, 
        0.62, 0.65]
        case .orange: return [0.35, 0.65]
        case .redAndBlue: return [0.65, 0.0]
        }
    }
    
    private var colors: [CGColor] {
        switch gradientType {
        case .blueAndRedOrange: return 
    [AppColors.blueLinkColor, AppColors.darkRed, 
     UIColor.orange, UIColor.orange, AppColors.darkRed, 
     AppColors.blueLinkColor].map { $0.cgColor }
        case .orange: return [UIColor.orange.cgColor]
        case .redAndBlue: return [AppColors.darkRed, 
    AppColors.blueLinkColor].map { $0.cgColor }
        }
    }
    
    private let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private let spacingFromEdges: CGFloat = 5
    private var radius: CGFloat { self.frame.width/2 - 
    spacingFromEdges }
    
    //  MARK: - Override functions
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    //  MARK: - Private functions
    private func addProgressBar(radius: CGFloat, progress: 
    CGFloat) {
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 
    bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY), radius: radius, startAngle: 
    CGFloat.pi, endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: 
    true)
    self.configureTrackLayer(with: circularPath, lineWidth: 
    lineWidth)
    self.configureProgressLayer(with: circularPath, lineWidth: 
    lineWidth)
        layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        self.addGradient()
        self.addAnimation()
    }
    
    private func configureTrackLayer(with circularPath: 
    UIBezierPath, lineWidth: CGFloat) {
        self.trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        self.trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.trackLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        self.trackLayer.lineCap = .butt
    }
    
    private func configureProgressLayer(with circularPath: 
    UIBezierPath, lineWidth: CGFloat) {
        self.shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        self.shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        self.shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        self.shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
        self.shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
        self.shapeLayer.mask = trackLayer
    }
    
    private func addGradient() {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = colors
        gradient.frame = bounds
        gradient.locations = location
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.7)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
        gradient.type = .conic
        gradient.mask = shapeLayer
        layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    }
    
    private func addAnimation() {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.toValue = progress/100.0
        animation.duration = CFTimeInterval((3 * progress)/100)
        animation.fillMode = .forwards
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        self.shapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "animation")
    }
    
}
```

Here is the Date extension:

```
    ///Converts the string into 'Date' if possible, based on the given date format and timezone. otherwise returns nil
    func toDate(dateFormat:String, timeZone:TimeZone = TimeZone.current) -> Date? {
        
        let frmtr = DateFormatter()
//        frmtr.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        frmtr.dateFormat = dateFormat
//        frmtr.timeZone = timeZone
        return frmtr.date(from: self)
    }
   
    var hour:Int{
    return (Calendar.current as NSCalendar).components(.hour, 
    from: self).hour!
    }
```

Use case for the SunProgressView:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: SunProgressView!

    private func setupProgressWithTime() {
    let startTime = "06:00".toDate(dateFormat: "HH:mm")!.hour
    let endTime = "18:00".toDate(dateFormat: "HH:mm")!.hour
    let total = endTime - startTime
    let currentTime = Date().hour
    let difference = currentTime - startTime
    let timeDifference = difference > 12 ? 0 : difference
    let ratio: Float = (Float(timeDifference)/Float(total)) * 100.0
    self.progressView.progress = CGFloat(ratio)
    }
```

i am using the progress view in case that it moves from 0 to 1 only in the time from 06:00 AM to 06:00 PM.

Here i want to add a sun image with the progress which is shown in the link above.

Comment: You would just superimpose that image separately. It's not part of the bezier path under it

Comment: How can i get the location of the end stroke in the UIBezierPath and how to superimpose the image over that ProgressView.
Thanks

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Comment: Provide your code that draws the bezier path and we may be able to help you update it to also draw your image. @sanjirambo's answer shows how to get the end-point of a Bezier Path, which is a big piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the coordinates from CAShapeLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60509975/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-from-cashapelayer)

Answer (score 2):

Can you look into [currentPoint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624352-currentpoint) property of UIBezierPath.

You can get the current endpoint from this property and can animate a UIImageView to follow the path.

Comment: Cool! I Did not know about UIBezierPath's `currentPoint` property. That does seem to solve the OPs problem nicely, and I learned something new. (Voted.)